# Need a Platform to create a simple App

Tags: flash, colors, platform

what is the easy to learn platform platform to create a colorful display and link it to hard coded some pages

Comment: Can you elaborate your question to explain what exactly you want to do??

Comment: I need to create a simple GUI which will have to look like screens off a mobile and i need to be able to click it to do some simple stuff like connect it to a hardcoded page or something. Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more customized UI of your application, rather than using Flash, I'll recommend you to go for Adobe AIR, since it is more capable when it comes to developing "real" applications (with wide set of APIs that it provides). There are other alternatives like WPF (Windows Presentation Foundation) and Silverlight but they're Windows ONLY and also, WPF is much heavy for such a simple application. And, AIR has clear advantage over WPF since its light-weight and runs on all major platforms, Windows, Mac and Linux.

You can find more information over starting development with AIR [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air.html).